# How to handle EOF / Ctrl+D in Go crypto/ssh session.Wait()

Tags: go, ssh

When I use `session.Shell()` to start a new shell on a remote server and then `session.Wait()` to run the session until the remote end exits the session does not gracefully handle using Ctrl+D to end the session.

I can make this work using `os/exec` to launch a local child process to run whatever copy of the ssh client is available locally, but I would prefer to do this with native Go.

Examle code snippet:

```
conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "some-server.fqdn", sshConfig)
if err != nil {
  return err
}
defer conn.Close()

session, err := conn.NewSession()
if err != nil {
  return err
}
defer session.Close()

session.Stdout = os.Stdout
session.Stderr = os.Stderr
session.Stdin = os.Stdin

modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
  ssh.ECHO:          0,
  ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400,
  ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400,
}

err = session.RequestPty("xterm", 80, 40, modes)
if err != nil {
  return err
}

err = session.Shell()
if err != nil {
  return err
}
session.Wait()
```

Running `exit` on the remote server gracefully hangs up the remote end and `session.Wait()` returns as expected, but sending an EOF with Ctrl+D causes the remote end to hang up but the call to `session.Wait()` is stuck blocking. I have to use Ctrl+C to SIGINT the Go program.
I would like to get both to gracefully exit the `session.Wait()` call as that is expected behavior for most interactive ssh sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this (with a bunch of additional framework code) but am not sure why it happens.  It is possible to terminate the session by adding a `session.Close` call if you encounter EOF on stdin:

```
        session.Stdout = os.Stdout
        session.Stderr = os.Stderr
        // session.Stdin = os.Stdin
        ip, err := session.StdinPipe()
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        go func() {
                io.Copy(ip, os.Stdin)
                fmt.Println("stdin ended")
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                fmt.Println("issuing ip.Close() now")
                ip.Close()
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                fmt.Println("issuing session.Close() now")
                err = session.Close()
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Printf("close: %v\n", err)
                }
        }()
```

You'll see that the session shuts down (not very nicely) after the `session.Close()`.  Calling `ip.Close()` *should* have shut down the stdin channel, and it seems like this *should* happen when just using `os.Stdin` directly too, but for some reason it does not work.  Debugging shows an ssh-channel-close message going to the other end (for both cases), but the other end doesn't close the return-data ssh channels, so your end continues to wait for more output from them.

Worth noting: you have not put the local tty into raw-ish character-at-a-time mode.  A regular ssh session does, so ^D does not actually *close* the connection, it just sends a literal control-D to the pty on the other side.  It's the other end that turns that control-D into a (soft) EOF signal on the pty.

Comment: It seems like the goroutine there should be internal to `session.Wait()`. The documentation suggests that it should return no matter how the connection was closed, just that under non-graceful terminations the err value will be populated.


Do you know of a way to get into the raw mode with the ssh package? I'd be interested in trying that. Sending the EOF to the remote end should cause bash to exit out nicely.

Comment: Not sure which goroutine you mean—there's already one that looks similar to the one above (but lacks the `session.Close()` part) that handles copying from the input stream to the other end of the session. As for getting raw mode, I don't know if there's anything convenient.